# Can ConvNets be used for real-time object recognition from video feed?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, classification, performance, real-time

Convolutional neural network are leading type of feed-forward artificial neural network for image recognition. Can they be used for real-time image recognition for videos (frame by frame), or it takes too much processing (assuming they're written in C-like language)?

For example for classification of type of animals based on the training from huge dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are getting there, with as usual some trade-off between quality and speed.

For example [Lecture 8: Spatial Localization and Detection lecture](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2016/winter1516_lecture8.pdf) shows some benchmarks (mAP = Mean Average Precision, higher is better; FPS = frame per second):

[image: Table/Performance: Real-Time Detectors]

[image: Table/Performance: R-CNN, Fast R-CNN, Faster R-CNN]